# On-chain poof for staking rewards payout

Tags: nearprotocol, near, nearprotocol-validator

I am trying to find out how the rewards are sent to the validators account/delegation contract. Where is that information stored and how can it be retrieved from the RPC nodes?

Comment: only thing I could find is the code that distributes the rewards but no documentation on this: https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/6815dce3e64115a6e4c3dd784929a74ee58b8dd3/chain/epoch_manager/src/reward_calculator.rs#L42